# Why do figures that can be tiled with two different polyominoes tend to be symmetric?

Tags: tiling, polyomino

Two polyominoes are **compatible** when there is a figure that can be tiled by both; a smallest one is called a **least common multiple**.

In looking through tables of these least common multiples of various polyominoes, I noticed that a vast majority are symmetric. (See http://www.recmath.org/PolyCur/pairwise.html and http://www.recmath.org/PolyCur/pairwise.html).

**Could someone explain why this is?**

Not all solutions are symmetric, here is an example:

[image] 
(Image from http://www.iread.it/Poly/P65.html)

[image] 
(Image from http://www.recmath.org/PolyCur/n8euph/n8euph.html)

Comment: My gut says symmetry allows for flexibility in tiling. It may be hard to quantify something like that, though. Also note that $180^\circ$ rotational symmetry (and nothing more) is the least amount of symmetry a polyomino-tiled figure could have (except no symmetry), and that's what many of those have. Maybe there isn't really that much symmetry there, relatively speaking. Also hard to quantify, of course.

Comment: My first thought is that the wallpaper groups could provide some insight into these symmetries. Rotational and glide reflection account for many of these examples.